# Google OAuth flow - passing the resulting tokens via querystring

Tags: security, asp.net-core, oauth, google-oauth, openid-connect

I'm reviewing some code that uses the OpenIdConnect OAuth flow in asp.net core to auth a user against Google. Once auth is established, there is a handler in `OnTicketRecieved` that takes the resulting access token and refresh token, and passes that to a different endpoint in the app:

```
OnTicketReceived = context =>
{
    string returnUrl = "/Somewhere/else";

    string refreshToken = context.Properties.Items.ContainsKey(".Token.refresh_token") ? context.Properties.Items[".Token.refresh_token"] : "none";
    string accessToken = context.Properties.Items.ContainsKey(".Token.access_token") ? context.Properties.Items[".Token.access_token"] : "none";
    var email = context.Principal.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email).Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
    returnUrl += $"?refreshToken={refreshToken}&accessToken={accessToken}&email={email}";

    context.ReturnUri = returnUrl + WebUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
},
```

My question is - how secure is this? It's effectively leaking refresh tokens that can be seen - although the scope of what you can do with them is very limited, being Google OAuth we're locked down to endpoints we can interact with, and the app secret would also need to be known in order to do anything malicious with these tokens

Thanks

Matt

Comment: To add on to this question, if the tokens are being passed as GET variables isn't there also a risk that they will be logged to access logs? If an attacker was able to gain system access and obtain the app secret as well as the access logs it seems like there could be big trouble. At a minimum, I would store the App Secret somewhere else like Vault.